# dealing with \n characters at end of multiline string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have been using python with regex to clean up a text file.  I have been using the following method and it has generally been working:

```
mystring = compiledRegex.sub("replacement",mystring)
```

The string in question is an entire text file that includes many embedded newlines. Some of the compiled regex's cover multiple lines using the `re.DOTALL` option.  If the last character in the compiled regex is a \n  the above command will substitute all matches of the regex except the match that ends with the final newline at the end of the string.  In fact, I have had several other no doubt related problems dealing with newlines and multiple newlines when they appear at the very end of the string.  Can anyone give me a pointer as to what is going on here?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give a (minimal) testcase for the problem?

Comment: ok.  One of the compiled expressions is: "TOTAL:.*?C2\n"  This expression will be matches multiple times in the file.  If I leave out the \n it will remove all but leaves newlines which cause blank lines.  If I include the \n it will not leave blank lines but will not delete the last match.

Comment: A more obvious example might be that if I were to create a compiled regex that matched "\n\n" so that I could sub "" (thus deleting blank lines) then the substitution would be successful on all "\n\n" except for the "\n\n" that appeared at the very end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet is that your file does not end with a newline...

```
>>> content = open('foo').read()
>>> print content
TOTAL:.?C2
abcTOTAL:AC2
defTOTAL:C2
>>> content
'TOTAL:.?C2\nabcTOTAL:AC2\ndefTOTAL:C2'
```

...so the last line does not match the regex:

```
>>> regex = re.compile('TOTAL:.*?C2\n', re.DOTALL)
>>> regex.sub("XXX", content)
'XXXabcXXXdefTOTAL:C2'
```

If that is the case, the solution is simple: just match either a newline or the end of the file (with `$`):

```
>>> regex = re.compile('TOTAL:.*?C2(\n|$)', re.DOTALL)
>>> regex.sub("XXX", content)
'XXXabcXXXdefXXX'
```

Comment: OK.  Same problem, much more simply stated:  I created a test file with several lines of text.  One of the lines in the middle of the file was followed by 2 newlines.  Also, there are 2 newlines at the very end of the file.  I read in the file from standard input and into a list which I immediately converted into a string called "fileAsString".  The compiled regex is doublenew =  re.compile('\n\n').  The substitution was done as fileAsString = doublenew.sub('\n', fileAsString)  The result is that the double new lines in the middle of the file are replaced with a single, but not the end double.

Comment: This is weird. I wrote `string = "This\n\nis\n\nan\n\ntest\n\n"` here in Python console, then `regex = re.compile("\n\n", re.DOTALL)` and then `regex.sub("\n", string)` The result was `'This\nis\nan\ntest\n'` as expected. How did you read the file from standard input? Have you used `sys.stdin.read()`? What is the result of `print(repr(fileAsString))`?

Answer (score 3):

If i correctly undestood you and all that you need is to get a text without newline at the end of the each line and then iterate over this text in order to find a required word than you can try to use the following:

```
data = (line for line in text.split('\n') if line.strip())# gives you all non empty lines without '\n'at the end
```

Now you can either search/replace any text you need using list slicing or regex functionality.

Or you can use replace in order to replace all '\n' to whenever you want:

```
text.replace('\n', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get a good handle on what is going on from your explanation but you may be able to fix it by replacing all multiple newlines with a single newline as you read in the file.  Another option might be to just trim() the regex removing the \n at the end unless you need it for something.

Comment: It seems that because the regex is matching lines of a file by default (and lines are defined by the \n character) and this is one long string with embedded newlines, python treats the final newlines different than the embedded ones?

Comment: are you sure that the file ends in a newline?

Comment: take a look at brandizzi's answer if that's the problem

Comment: Yes, on a second look brandizzi's answer did solve it (I think).  I did was not understanding that $ ends the string not the character before the nearest newline.  Usually strings end with the first newline and that is not the case here. I have been confused.  Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the question mark to prevent the regex matching more than one iine at a time? If so then you probably want to be using the MULTILINE flag instead of DOTALL flag. The ^ sign will now match just after a new line or the beginning of a string and the $ sign will now match just before a newline character or the end of a string. 
eg.

```
regex = re.compile('^TOTAL:.*$', re.MULTILINE)
content = regex.sub('', content)
```

However, this still leaves with the problem of empty lines. But why not just run one additional regex at the end that removes blank lines.

```
regex = re.compile('\n{2,}')
content = regex.sub('\n', content)
```